# Is it possible to create a FastCGI exe from Powerbuilder 11.5 that can GET the QUERY_STRINGfrom the url its being called through commandline?

Tags: fastcgi, powerbuilder

1. I am trying to create a powerbuiler EXE that generates a pdf report by taking a commandline parameter.
2. I want to call this EXE from the browser by passing a query_string after registering it as a fastcgi module in iis 7 (only way i know)

My problem is i am able to call the exe from the browser but unable to get the query_string through commandline that was passed in the url.

Any help is would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a FastCGI exe in C/C++ that uses PBNI to execute PowerBuilder code.

How are you creating the FastCGI exe?

Comment: I am just treating the powerbuilder exe as the fastcgi exe and registering in iis. Although it shows some error in browser for not returning a complete http header. That does not matter for me as the exe is executing and generating my pdf but only not getting the parameters from url

Comment: I wrote an ISAPI Extension in C that uses PBNI to call PowerBuilder code generically. You can download and use for free from here: http://www.topwizprogramming.com/tools.html. It is the bottom link PBDotWeb.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe write it using Visual Studio (the tool has nice templates/wizards for making IIS Modules and Handlers which is the replacement for using CGI. You could then maybe use the .NET assembly a PB program but PB 11.5 is .Net version 3 (I think) so keep that in mind.

I actually wrote a crude datawindow like code generator using IIS [Modules/Handlers](http://www.iis.net/learn/develop/runtime-extensibility/developing-iis-modules-and-handlers-with-the-net-framework) (in Visual Studio .NET C#) and have the program process files with a ".pb" extension via settings in IIS. The program parses out the dataobject code and handles some of the generic datawindow stuff using the dataobject. This would be a great open source project as long as it was unique enough it didn't violate any patents.

I tried creating a Module/Handler **using** PB12.5 and was not successful but CGI might work but I haven't tried them.

Answer (score -1):

You need to pass through the arguements to the exe. A direct call to an EXE file within a web server is not possible. You could do this by using PHP or ASP.NET.

All what you need to do is to collect the GET Parameter that is send through this called web page and then start the external proccess.

In PHP it would be `$sAnswer = shellexec('path\\to\\some\\exe.exe param1 param2 ...');` and in C# it would be `Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/C path\\to\\some.exe param1 param2 ...");`

You´ll got all your GET parameter in `$_GET` by using PHP. In case of using C# it would be something like `request` (not sure now where you can get the request object using ASP.NET).

Comment: No need for PHP or ASP if the web server is set up to handle the execution of cgi. With Apache, a `AddHandler cgi-script .cgi` followed by `Options +ExecCGI` is enough to exchange data with an exe.

Comment: Actually i am using php, i tried the exec, shellexec, passthru way but when i call my powerbuilder exe, it executes the exe but generates 0kb pdf(i use ghostscript to save as dw), seems some kind of permission issue in iis or i dont know. Thanks a lot.

Comment: sounds like your arguements won´t getting through your powerbuilder exe. This is very complex to get something like this working. Have you googled about that why it´s not working?